# Parsing XML using Python on SelectSingleNode

Tags: python, xml, xpath, ironpython

Using the following XML data i want to get value for relevant keys that i'm calling through the python code. And i want to accomplish this task without using any 3rd party libraries.

```
<Userinfo>
  <UserData>
     <item key="DateOfBirth" value="19851103" />
     <item key="FirstName" value="John" />
     <item key="LastName" value="Dicaprio" />
     <item key="Gender" value="M" />
     <item key="Email" value="john@abc.com" />
     <item key="ContactNo" value="235625341" />
  </UserData>
</Userinfo>
```

From the above xml code i want to extract the value from the key i'm calling within the python code below.

```
def ExtractXml(args):
url = '....'
wc = System.Net.WebClient()
xml = wc.DownloadString(url)
doc = System.Xml.XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xml)
root = doc.DocumentElement
nsmgr = System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
#nsmgr.AddNamespace('ns','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')
node = root.SelectNodes('/Userinfo/UserData',nsmgr)
tcount=root.SelectNodes('/Userinfo/UserData').Count

if not node: 
    ServiceDesk.Log.PrintError('No condition node')
    return

r=[]
t={}

counts=0
for itemNode in node:
    counts += 1
    fullname = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("/item[@key='FirstName']/@value",nsmgr))
    empname = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("/item[@key='LastName']/@value",nsmgr))
    cardcountry = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("/item[@key='Email']/@value",nsmgr))
    #birthdate = ServiceDesk.Common.ParseDateTime(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("item[@key='DateOfBirth']"))

    t = {'counter':counts,'FirstName':fullname,'LastName':empname,'Email':cardcountry,'__rowid__':counter,'__totalcount__':tcount}
    r.append(t)
return r
```

Using following code it doesn't retrive the value for relevant key on SelectSingleNode call. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about IronPython, but Python's core library includes some other platform independent XML parsers... Here's an example that uses `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

```
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<Userinfo>
    <UserData>
        <item key="DateOfBirth" value="19851103" />
        <item key="FirstName" value="John" />
        <item key="LastName" value="Dicaprio" />
        <item key="Gender" value="M" />
        <item key="Email" value="john@abc.com" />
        <item key="ContactNo" value="235625341" />
    </UserData>
</Userinfo>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
fname = root.findall(".//item[@key='FirstName']")[0].get('value')
dob = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        root.findall(".//item[@key='DateOfBirth']")[0].get('value'),
        '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Before I posted, I did check to see whether ElementTree is included in IronPython (it does appear to be https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: I'm getting this error, 'LightException' object has no attribute 'etree'

Answer (score 0):

Currently the XPath expressions in the `for` loop are all relative to document node since it started with `/`. To make it relative to context element, which in this case is referenced by `itemNode`, you can either add a preceding `.` or just remove the `/` completely :

```
for itemNode in node:
    counts += 1
    # here are some ways to make your XPath heeds the context element `itemNode`
    fullname = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("./item[@key='FirstName']/@value",nsmgr))
    empname = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("item[@key='LastName']/@value",nsmgr))
    cardcountry = xstr(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("self::*/item[@key='Email']/@value",nsmgr))
```

Comment: Does the actual XML has namespaces, specifically default namespace?